# C# Check if contains various combination of substring

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, ocr

I want to check If my OCR result (a string) is either "No Edge" or "No Signal".

Problem is sometimes I would get `N0 Edge`, `No Signa1`, `N0 signa1`, `No 5ignal`, etc. The letter `o`, `S`, `i` and `l` can sometimes become digits or something else. Unfortunately there is nothing else I can do regarding the OCR.

Currently I am doing this:

```
ocrResult = ocrResult.ToLower();
if (ocrResult.Contains("edg") || ocrResult.Contains("gna"))
{
    //no edge or no signal
}

else
{
    //Not no edge or no signal
}
```

Can any of you please suggest a smarter approach?

Comment: check for regular expressions.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh regular expressions only make the problem a little more concise...

Comment: don't you think that's enough help.

Comment: No, because he would benefit way more from a smart way to "normalize" the numbers to the correct representation. Using regular expressions would only change the two calls to "Contains" into one single regex match.

Comment: @Areks the wrong result doesn't always contain numbers. Sometimes letter `L` can be read as backslash.

Comment: In your tests are at least letters that always are read correctly (don't have to be contiguous), with regex we could ignore the mis-read characters and focus in those that are always correct.

Comment: The letter o, S, i and l can sometimes become what? please explain which type of character may there

Comment: Have you considered string metric algorithms such as [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: Perhaps a 'fuzzy string search' algorithm could help. Or perhaps a custom string comparison method that scores characters based on their similarity in shape - a sufficiently high score would indicate a possible match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a library called **Simila** which is designed for such scenarios:

In **Simila** you can have this:

```
// A similarity engine which accepts similar if similarity is more than 70%
var simila = new Simila() { Treshold = 0.7 };

if (simila.AreSimilar(ocrResult, "No Edge") || simila.AreSimilar(ocrResult, "No Signal"))
{
    // ...
}
```

A simple documentation of Simila is available here:

https://github.com/mehrandvd/Simila/wiki

FYI, I'm working on it and it is still in beta version. Let me know if an early release helps you, so I can create an early beta release for you.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for! If this works it's gonna solve so many problems I currently have! It would be great if I can have a try on the beta release! :)

Comment: This is a really interesting project. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I've just created an early pre-release just for you ;) Please check if it helps..

Comment: @Areks I'm really happy you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are doing works just keep doing it, it's simple, easy to understand and scanning a 9 letter string twice isn't likely to cause performance issues unless you have really big data sets.

Just add a comment so that someone who looks at this code years from now know why you are looking for seemingly random substrings.

If this isn't working then what you are looking for is a "classification algorithm" (Wikipedia list's 79 of them) - but they can get complex and choosing the right one can be tricky so they truly an overkill if simple string comparison does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Well the .lower is slower then a comparison that ignores the case. Certainly if u use it in a loop. So at first i recommend you do a comparison that ignores the case. For readability and maintainability i advice u refactor the comparison. And finally u should check if the string is empty or null, then u do not have to compare the string.

Example:

```
if (IsThereNoEdgeOrNoSignal(ocrResult))
{
   //no edge or no signal
}
else
{
  //Not no edge or no signal
}    

private static bool IsThereNoEdgeOrNoSignal(string ocrResult)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ocrResult))
            return false;

        return ocrResult.IndexOf("edg", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 || ocrResult.IndexOf("gna", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

if it only stays to these two strings, then you should keep it this way, does it grows with more possibilities you should check it with a regular expression.

I hope this helps u.